# I've installed a GUI app to run with pip, now how do i run it?

Tags: python, macos, pip

It seems like a stupidly simple problem, I've installed the youtube-dlg program using pip on MacOS Sierra 10.12.3, got my dependencies in order through some struggling (wxpython3 instead of version 4), etc., and then now that I've gotten to a point where everything seems to be installed where it should be fit to run, I can't seem to figure out how. Here's where I got to.

```
$ sudo -H pip install youtube-dlg
Requirement already satisfied: youtube-dlg in 
/private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

My question is, how do I simply run youtube-dlg? The app name and path are listed, and I'm naively stuck on where to go next. This may be a pathing issue I'm not aware of. I was hoping to run it once and find a way to keep it either pinned to the Dock or in Apps seeing as it is a GUI. Getting this to work on windows was easy enough, but unfortunately in the OS world I am master of none, user of many.

Comment: Perhaps `import youtube_dl_gui; youtube_dl_gui.main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all I needed to do was `python youtube-dlg`
I am a dummy! For anyone else that might be having troubles with youtube-dlg, make sure you are on wxpython version 3. The current version is 4. Here is a working link for the one I found. https://wxpython.org/snapshots/wxPython3.0-osx-3.0.3.0.b20160914-cocoa-py2.7.dmg